# Validacion usuarios SQL - visual.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer mas fácil un proceso en un sistema ya establecido y quiero que realice la misma validación del sistema que ya esta funcionando.

El sistema que ya esta creado hace la validación de usuario y contraseña a SQL Server pero no desde la tabla usuarios que se encuentra en la BD, esta se realiza desde el inicio de sesión de SQL (Carpeta Security - Logins)

[image: Carpetas SQL]

He estado buscando pero la información que encuentro me ayuda a hacer la validación desde la la tabla de usuarios.
El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
conexion.Open()
    Dim consulta As String = "select login_id, password from usuarios where login_id = '" & TxtUsuario.Text & "' and password = '" & TxtContraseña.Text & "'"
    cmd = New SqlCommand(consulta, conexion)
        Dim lector As SqlDataReader
        lector = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If lector.HasRows Then
        Dim menu As New Menu
        menu.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Este usuario no existe")
    End If
        conexion.Close()
```

Desde ya gracias por los aportes

Comment: No se entiende del todo la pregunta. Puedes darle a [edit](/edit) para modificarla y anotar las aclaraciones que sean oportunas. ¿Cuál es el objetivo final?. Los logins no son elementos para conocimiento del usuario. Además el código que has expuesto, no debería de concatenar el texto directamente a la consulta, debería de usar SqlParameters. Puedes buscar Inyección SQL.

Comment: Creo que debes de primero consultar más acerca de la diferencia entre USER y LOGIN y luego reformular la pregunta ya que no estás definiendo cuál es el problema o error.